# Кажущемся или кажущимся?

Tags: орфография

"Я умираю в этом призрачном мире; что изменилось бы, если б я умирал в мире, кажущемся не только мне, но и всем прочим, более реальным, чем этот?"
Может быть, следует писать "кажущимся"?
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: В мире (какОм?) кажущЕмся. Других вариантов в этом предложении нет.  Умираю (какИм?) кажущИмся не подходит.